# How to loop over `. . .` in an R function

Tags: r, function, plot, lapply

I have a function called `foo()`. The arguments are `...`.

But I want loop over the individual arguments in `...`. For example, if user inputs `col = c(2,3)`, I want the first round of `lapply()` to use `col = 2` and the second round of `lapply()` to use `col = 3` and so on.

Is this possible in R?

Reproducible R code:

```
foo <- function(...){
  
  x <- list(...)
  n_plots <- lengths(x)[1]
    
  par(mfrow = n2mfrow(n_plots))
  
  lapply(1:n_plots, \(i) plot(1:10, ...))
  
}
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(col = 2:3, pch = c(19,21))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little convoluted (uses `...` twice) but seems to do the trick, for an arbitrary number of arguments:

```r
foo <- function(...){
  L <- list(...)
  n_plots <- lengths(L)[1]  
  par(mfrow = n2mfrow(n_plots))
  ff <- function(...) {
     args <- c(list(x = 1:10), list(...))
     do.call(plot, args)
  }
  Map(ff, ...)
}
```

```r
foo(col = 2:3, pch = c(19,21), cex = 2:3)
```